# VAR model in satatsmodels (autoregression)

Tags: statsmodels

What is the exog_future in `VARResults.forecast(y, steps, exog_future=None)`?

I have my exog and endog, but in forcasting function, I dont know what to put in exog_future?

I am sure is not None because I have an exog set!

Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide values for the exog during the forecast period. If you cannot provide it, then you could include it in the VAR or use a separate forecast for it.

exog could be a deterministic variable like trend or seasonal dummies that we can define based on the time periods or time index.

For some variables we might have a better external estimate, for example if one exog is temperature and we have a weather forecast for the forecast period.

In scenario analysis and decision variables, we might want to forecast for different given paths of the explanatory variable, for example what is the forecast if we lower the price by 10 % compared to historical average or trend.

Comment: Thanks. I got the concept of the exog now! I thought that the exog is our input and endog are outputs that are forcasted by the exog!! so it is wrong! So which statistic model I should use, If I have some dependent variable Y to be forecasted by some some independent variables X using time series? Is python providing some packages such that we can get results for Y_t= CX_(t-1)?

Comment: you can use past values of the explanatory variables, but you have to create the lagged exog yourself, AFAIK there is no model in statsmodels that does this automatically. In VAR every `endog` depends on past values of all `endog` directly.